# Slickgrid Merging cells

Tags: slickgrid

is it possible to get the below structure for slickgrid

```
 Product  | Features
```

---

```
 TV       |  Color
          |  HD
          |
          | 3D
```

---

Something as below

[image]
Here i have to merge the 1 column for all the rows whose product is TV. How do we implement this in slickgrid

JSON iam getting is [{"id":"1","product":"tv","feature":"color"}, {"id":"1","product":"tv","feature":"HD"}, {"id":"1","product":"tv","feature":"3D"}]

Please suggest how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to merge this cells?

It'll be much easier when you  group data based on product (it isn't difficult using underscore.js for example), and make formatter with that features join by new line.

Excel-like merging cell will be very very difficult to implement.